# Why can't I concatenate two Strings together, but I can concatenate a String and a &str?

Tags: string, rust, concatenation

[The Rust Book, Chapter 4 under *"Ways Variables and Data Interact: Clone"*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html#ways-variables-and-data-interact-clone) says you can use `.clone` to set `s2` to `s1` like this

```rust
let s1 = String::from("hello");
let s2 = s1.clone();

println!("s1 = {}, s2 = {}", s1, s2);
```

Why can't I change `s2` to be `s1.clone()` + `s1.clone()`

```rust
let s1 = String::from("hello");
let s2 = s1.clone() + s1.clone();

println!("s1 = {}, s2 = {}", s1, s2);
```

When I try to compile that, I get

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:3:24
  |
3 |     let s2 = s1.clone() + s1.clone();
  |                           ^^^^^^^^^^
  |                           |
  |                           expected `&str`, found struct `String`
  |                           help: consider borrowing here: `&s1`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `comment` due to previous error
```

I realize I can fix the second part by changing `s1.clone()` to `&s1.clone()`, but why is this required?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`Add` instance for strings](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Add.html#impl-Add%3C%26str%3E-for-String) takes a `String` on the left and a `&str` on the right. This consumes the string on the left and extends it with (a copy of) the string on the right. It does this for efficiency reasons, to avoid having to copy both strings in every case.

So when you want to concatenate two strings in Rust with `+`, the left-hand side needs to be a `String` (an owned string) and the right-hand side needs to be a `&str` (a borrowed string slice). So consider

```
let s2 = s1.clone() + &s1.clone();
```

or, since we're borrowing it, there's no need for the second clone at all.

```
let s2 = s1.clone() + &s1;
```

Comment: I don't think this _fully_ answer question because even if it takes a `&str` on the right, all `String` should coerce to `&str`, right? There is an [`impl AsRef<str> for String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html#2575), and you can actually do that explicitly: `let s2 = s1.clone() + s1.as_ref();`. But why doesn't it happen implicitly?

Comment: @EvanCarroll I don't think `AsRef` ever gets involved in implicit coercions. I don't see it listed on [the relevant page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html#coercion-types), which lists `Deref` but not `AsRef`. So Rust could go from `&String` to `&str` implicitly (that's what `Deref` does), but it won't convert a `String` (non-reference) to `&str` for you.

Comment: but there is actually an impl for Deref too that takes a String to a `&str`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html#2408

Comment: @EvanCarroll Not quite. There's a `Deref` that will take `&String` to `&str`. Every `Deref` implementation takes `&self` to `&Target` (it's always references, never owned values). Rust isn't going to insert a borrow on the right-hand side of a `+`. The *only* time Rust will do that is when calling a method, where the receiver can be treated as `self`, `&self`, or `&mut self` as needed, for convenience.